# How to mock a RIA service

Tags: .net, silverlight, mocking, ria

Is there any ability to mock methods that are provided with RIA Services?

I would like to test my Silverlight App without communication to the server side...

I see a following approach:

- create a separate interface;
- add it to "base classes" for my RiaService;
- define each autogenerated RIA-method in this interface;
- insert dependency so that my "functionality" will depend not from the RiaService, but from the interface that is implemented with RiaService.

But for this case I see a problem: how to keep my interface in the auto-generated files?

ANy thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few relatively unrelated (to each other) thoughts...

1. If the auto-generated files are partial classes, you could simply add another partial class to define that it implements an interface.
2. You could use [StructureMap](http://structuremap.github.com/structuremap/index.html) to inject dependencies to [Moq objects](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) to do what you want.
3. Use generics in an interesting way to allow you to use either the generated class or the mocked object. (probably not a good solution)
4. Use reflection to work with the two different object types. (probably not a good option)
5. Compile directives (#if DEBUG) to use the two different object types. (definitely not a good option)

Hope this either helps or inspires some good/better ideas!

Comment: Some additional links that might help: http://www.nikhilk.net/NET-RIA-Services-ViewModel-Pattern-2.aspx http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/110292/249721.aspx